# BigDecimal stripTrailingZeros and equality

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Given

```
BigDecimal a = ...;
BigDecimal b = ...;
```

Do the following hold for *all possible values* of `a` and `b`?

```
if (a.compareTo(b) == 0)
    assert a.stripTrailingZeros().equals(b.stripTrailingZeros())
if (a.compareTo(b) != 0)
    assert !(a.stripTrailingZeros().equals(b.stripTrailingZeros()))

if (a.stripTrailingZeros().equals(b.stripTrailingZeros()))
    assert(a.compareTo(b) == 0)
if (!(a.stripTrailingZeros().equals(b.stripTrailingZeros())))
    assert(a.compareTo(b) != 0)
```

Or is there some edge case where the above assertions are not all true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `stripTrailingZeros` can throw an `ArithmeticException` if the resulting `scale` overflows. For example;

```
new BigDecimal(
        new BigInteger("70"),
        Integer.MIN_VALUE
).stripTrailingZeros(); // tries to set the scale to Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1 but can't
```

Other than such cases, the assertion should be true, because there is only one unique `BigDecimal` representation of each number, that has no trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

`BigDecimal.equals()` says

> Unlike compareTo, this method considers two BigDecimal objects equal only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to 2.00 when compared by this method).

So while you might be able to get differing results with `equals()` using `compareTo()` won't be confused by the (possible) scale changes done with `stripTrailingZeros()`:

> For example, stripping the trailing zeros from the BigDecimal value 600.0, which has [BigInteger, scale] components equals to [6000, 1], yields 6E2 with [BigInteger, scale] components equals to [6, -2]. If this BigDecimal is numerically equal to zero, then BigDecimal.ZERO is returned.

Since BigDecimal also doesn't support `NaN` or infinities, there's no tricky edge cases like `NaN != NaN` that would cause issues (besides the standard risks of floating point usage).

Answer (score 0):

`a.compareTo(b)` is either `0` or something else. There is no third possibility where it is not `0` nor something else.

`a.stripTrailingZeros().equals(b.stripTrailingZeros())` is either `true` or not `true`. There is no third possibility.

So, the answer is **yes**.